# span inside .addthis_button_facebook_like gets width of 450px after like, breaks addThis layout

Tags: facebook-like, addthis

So yeah, I have this on the page:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " id="divAddThis" runat="server">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" style="opacity:1;" <%="fb:like:layout='button_count'"%>></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
```

But after clicking the like button (and closing the bubble), a `<span>` just inside the `<fb:like ...>` element dynamically gets a width of 450px, breaking the layout of AddThis (the buttons are all inline).

Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it might be a bug on Facebook's side of things. I've seen a few reports pop up this week and I'm experiencing it myself as well.

Here is a link to one of the bug reports for it that says that Facebook is looking into it:

[Facebook Bug Report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325737700856317)

Hopefully we'll have an answer soon.